# Implicit WPF syles in non-WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I have a couple different applications where this would be helpful, but for the sake of a concrete example, let us suppose I have a WinForms application.

This application makes use of WPF controls within `ElementHost` objects.  I now would like to define an implicit style for all WPF Buttons (`System.Windows.Controls.Button`) so that every `ElementHost` does not need to merge in the resource dictionary nor does every `Button` need to explicitly specify the style.

Where do I define said style?

I have tried creating the resource dictionary `Themes\Generic.xaml` in the project root and specifying

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly )]
```

in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`.  This did not work and I am under the impression that that styles there are only for custom controls defined in the same assembly, where as `Button` is defined in a foreign assembly.

Examples place implicit style code in `<Application.Resources>`; however, that node is with-in `App.xaml`, which (the project not having started its life as a WPF application) does not exist.  Is it possible to add an `App.xaml` or is there some other place to put `<Application.Resources>` such that they are recognized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dr WPF has several suggestions:
http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/

Some relevant parts quoted below:

---

**Create an Application Instance and Add Resources in Code**
Below is a very simple function that will create the Application object if it does not exist and then load some resources:

```
public static void EnsureApplicationResources()
{
    if (Application.Current == null)
    {
        // create the Application object
        new Application();

        // merge in your application resources
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
            Application.LoadComponent(
               new Uri("MyLibrary;component/Resources/MyResourceDictionary.xaml",
               UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary);
    }
}
```

Now you just need to make sure that you call this function prior to parsing any XAML files that contain static resource references to application-level resources. To do this, simply add a call to the above function in the constructor of your markup-based classes before any call to `InitializeComponent()`:

```
public Page1()
{
    EnsureApplicationResources();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

---

**Define the Application Class in XAML and Create It on the Fly**
First, we do not want MSBuild to generate an application entry point for our Application class. So instead of declaring the `App.xaml` file as an `ApplicationDefinition` element in the project file, we need to declare it as a `Page` element:

```
<Page Include="App.xaml" />
<Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Next, we need to make sure that our `App.xaml` markup is parsed. Typically, this is done as part of the entry point function (which we just eliminated). Instead, we can simply define a constructor for the `Application` class and call `InitializeComponent` directly:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Now all our resources and merged dictionaries can be declared in `App.xaml` and our static function to load the Application instance can be as simple as this:

```
public static void EnsureApplicationResources()
{
    if (Application.Current == null)
    {
        // create the Application object
        new App();
    }
}
```

---

**Manage a Collection of Resource Dictionaries in Code and Merge them at the Element Level**
In this scenario, we do not leverage an `Application` object at all. Instead, we dynamically load each `ResourceDictionary` at runtime and selectively merge it into pages or windows or specific elements, as necessary.

```
public static class SharedResources
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MergedDictionariesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MergedDictionaries",
            typeof(string), typeof(SharedResources),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((string)null,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMergedDictionariesChanged)));

    public static string GetMergedDictionaries(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(MergedDictionariesProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMergedDictionaries(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(MergedDictionariesProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnMergedDictionariesChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValue as string))
        {
            foreach (string dictionaryName in (e.NewValue as string).Split(';'))
            {
                ResourceDictionary dictionary = GetResourceDictionary(dictionaryName);
                if (dictionary != null)
                {
                    if (d is FrameworkElement)
                    {
                        (d as FrameworkElement).Resources
                            .MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
                    }
                    else if (d is FrameworkContentElement)
                    {
                        (d as FrameworkContentElement).Resources
                            .MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static ResourceDictionary GetResourceDictionary(string dictionaryName)
    {
        ResourceDictionary result = null;
        if (_sharedDictionaries.ContainsKey(dictionaryName))
        {
            result = _sharedDictionaries[dictionaryName].Target;
        }
        if (result == null)
        {
            string assemblyName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.Name);
            result = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(assemblyName
                + ";component/Resources/" + dictionaryName + ".xaml",
                UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;
            _sharedDictionaries[dictionaryName] = new WeakReference(result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, WeakReference> _sharedDictionaries
        = new Dictionary<string, WeakReference>();
}
```

This would allow us to merge in shared resource dictionaries to the Resources collection of any framework element, by simply doing this:

```
<Grid dw:SharedResources.MergedDictionaries="ApplicationBrushes;ButtonStyles">
```

Comment: Things have come up and I am not able to test this in the immediate, but looks very promising.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Dr WPF App.xaml method to work mentioned in the previous answer. I added a new page to my WPF User Control assembly that is loaded by my WinForms app from a hosted control.  I copied the real App.xaml.cs from my other WPF client application that loads all the same resources.  I copied it's contents into this new "page", updating the namespaces and references as necessary.  I added the EnsureApplicationResources static method into the new App.xaml.cs App class.

It looks like this:

```
public static void EnsureApplicationResources() {
            if (Application.Current == null) {
                // create the Application object
                try {
                    new App() {
                        ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
                    };
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex) {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

The trick was figuring out the right place to call it to instantiate the app. My WinForms app launches WPF windows from several places, so my first attempt which involved calling the Ensure... method from within the root window's constructor did not work because there may actually be more than one "root window" instantiated.  It also wasn't disposing of the WPF App reliably so it subsequently threw exceptions when it tried to re-create the same app again even though Application.Current appears null.

Instead I added it to my startup routine in the WinForms app.  I don't use a start up object in that project. Instead I opt for the explicit control that a Main() subroutine gives.  The WinForms app is in VB.NET by the way.

```
Public Module MyWinFormsApp

    Public Sub Main()
        MyWpfApp.App.EnsureApplicationResources()
        Application.Run(New frmWinFormsMain())
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown()
    End Sub
End Module
```

This approach works perfectly. The WPF App is created when the WinForms app starts up and shut down when it shuts down and is available with any App scoped resources to all of my hosted WPF controls including implicit styles, etc.